# Getting ngx.balancer Lua module for nginx with apt

Tags: package-management, nginx

I have installed nginx and Lua for nginx from `nginx-extras` package and enabled Lua in my nginx config with `load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so; load_module "modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so";`.

However, when I try to `require "ngx.balancer"` in Lua code in nginx config, nginx returns error 500, unable to find the module. I have run `find`, and it seems that the Lua module `ngx.balancer` is not present.

Is there an Ubuntu package that would install `ngx.balancer`? I would like to avoid building anything from source.

Answer (score 0):

You need install two libraries "lua-resty-core" and "lua-resty-lrucache" from [OpenResty](https://github.com/openresty).
Then init it in nginx, like:

```
http {
   lua_package_path "/usr/local/lib/lua/?.lua;;";

   init_by_lua_block {
     require "resty.core"
     collectgarbage("collect")  -- just to collect any garbage
   }
}
```

Or simple use [OpenResty web platform](http://openresty.org/en/).